# C# WPF project with reference to F# ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, f#

I have project named FSharpProject in whick there is code like this:

```ml
module FSharpProject.ViewModel

type A =
    member x.a = 1
```

In other project(typical wpf application writing in C#) which have reference to FSharpProject I have xaml file like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="CSharpProjectView"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSharpProjectView"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:FSharpProject.ViewModel;assembly=FSharpProject"            
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="LogDataTemplate" DataType="{data:A}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" />                
            </DataTemplate>
```

But I get error that data:A type not found.

---

UPD: It does not work:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="CSharpProjectView"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSharpProjectView"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:FSharpProject;assembly=FSharpProject"            
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="LogDataTemplate" DataType="{data:ViewModel.A}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" />                
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: So are you writing C# or F#?

Comment: Project named CSharpProjectView writing in C# and use project named FSharpProject via reference. CSharpProjectView is a typical wpf application with only one difference - in its constructor haves code like this: this.DataContext = FSharpProject.ViewModel;

Comment: Why do you have curly braces around the DataType value? It should be "data:A" or "{x:Type data:A}"

Comment: You are right. Is the answer. I used it from -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400532/display-multiple-types-from-a-single-list-in-a-wpf-listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataType` should be simply `data:A` or `{x:Type data:A}`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LogDataTemplate" DataType="data:A">
```