# Means of generating an editable form from XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

```
<press_limits value="1055" label="Press Limits"  type="single 317" format="object">
  <projected_area value="0.052944637336319995" label="Projected area of part"  type="real(m*m)"/>
  <press_tonnage value="500.0" label="Press tonnage"  type="real(g)" units="0Ton"/>
  <within_press_limit value="1" label="within limits of press"  type="boolean"/>
```

From XML like the above, the XAML below will generate a form that displays the values, with appropriate controls and value formats.  But I can't get the stuff converted back.  ***I fail to see a simple change that will meet the requirements of Binding.  Perhaps fixing this requires an architecture change.  How can I do this differently?***

The magic starts here.  Bind this ItemsControl to an XmlElement, and it builds a ControlChooser for each subelement.

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate><WrapPanel/></ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <W3V:ControlChooser Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ControlChooser` triggers on the format attribute:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@format}" Value="spin">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource combo}" />
    </DataTrigger>
```

to pick a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="combo" > <W3V:ComboView /> </DataTemplate>
```

which instatiates the following control:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboButtonStyle}" Width="200"
     Text="{Binding Path=.,  ## PROBLEM, BUT HOW TO AVOID?
            Converter={StaticResource valueFormattingConverter },
            IsEditable="True" />
```

`valueFormattingConverter` uses the @units, @type, and @value attributes to produce properly formatted text.  The trouble is, this doesn't convert back.  I asked here: [TextBox ConvertBack event doesn't fire for XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987019/textbox-convertback-event-doesnt-fire-for-xml-element), and learned that it is impossible for Path=. to be used as '.' is an object but not a dependency property.

So then, I need a way to provide a `DependencyProperty` for `Binding`.  So `ComboView` needs to receive an object that has a property which is or has the `XmlElement` I want.  I think this means I really need to change things around but haven't the slightest idea how.  Maybe there's an MVVM approach to doing this???  Any insights will be appreciated.

An upcoming issue is a need to validate the data typed in and process the information.

Answer (score 1):

The MVVM method: pull the data out of the XML file, and put it a class which is the ViewModel. Each property in the ViewModel corresponds to an item of data in the XML file. Then use a custom `DataTemplate` to render the contents of the ViewModel to the screen.

We can extend this to render a *list* of items. Each item in the list is a ViewModel.  A `DataTemplate` always renders based on the type of the property it is attached to. So you can have a list of objects, and a custom `DataTemplate` for each item in the list. Of course, all of the items in the list would have to inherit from the same type.

This means you can have a list of items, and each item can render differently depending on the type of data in the XML file. This means that each item in the list can have a custom look and feel with different number of decimal places, colors, etc.

I've used this technique before, and it works well.

**Update**

For examples, see:

- http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3400532/display-multiple-types-from-a-single-list-in-a-wpf-listbox.

Comment: Please vote this answer up so it is ranked above my previous answer (which is not as good, to be honest).

Comment: The examples aren't quite where I want to be, but I have been researching the topic further and I think ObservableCollection is something I want to be using.  Building a live wrapper for a particular XmlElement is my plan.

Answer (score 0):

If I was solving this, I would look at generating C# on the fly. Here is how I would do it:

- All XAML compiles to a series of C# commands.
- I would set the XAML to format things the way I like it.
- I would find the equivalent C# code.
- I would then insert the appropriate if/else statements to alter the C# to suit.

Another method that I would try:

- Its possible to render custom XAML into an area on the screen.
- I would edit the XAML, based on the XML, then display this custom XAML on the screen.

I'd be curious to know if either of these methods work in practice, or if there is a better method that would work.

Comment: Compiling C# on the customer's computer?  That's not going to fly.  I think custom XAML also involves generating C# and that's equally not going to work.  (Unless you can explain how it can work.)  My best guess for an approach is a class that wraps my XML into another structure.  Hopefully still exposing XPath.

Comment: Slight misunderstanding - I never implied compiling C# code. If you have the equivalent C# code, you could alter it on the fly using if statements to create the output.

Comment: On further thought, my other answer is more likely to work well.